# Is ReactiveUI.Blazor ready for use ? .. Are there any examples?

Tags: reactiveui, blazor-server-side

.. I'm new to ReactiveUI ..

trying to use ReactiveUI.Blazor  .. in Blazor Server Side

.. it has been released but I can't see any examples in the solution 
https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/tree/master/src/ReactiveUI.Blazor

The only example I can find of Blazor with ReactiveUI
is https://github.com/Nethereum/NethereumBlazor 
and it's just using ReactiveUI 
.. not ReactiveUI.Blazor

Any one using ReactiveUI.Blazor ?

cheers in advance
Stu

Comment: As stated in the release notes it's preview https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases/tag/10.0.1

Comment: We do have some users making use of Blazor though. They are on the main slack channel so join there if you want to find some tips.

Comment: Cheers Glenn.. I didn't pick up on it being preview ( I know .net core 3.0 won't be release for another couple of days tho' ;-))... I thought there might be a code sample that shows how to use the reactive base components.. I'll head over to slack thanks again for the heads up

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: I had an amazing experience working with Reactive.Blazor in a WASM Blazor application and can absolutely recommend using it.

I used ReactiveUI.Blazor together with Blazorise in platform for managing offers in a more structured way to perform estimates based on the structured (meta)data of the offers.

I used the WASM version of Blazor and my experience was very good. Reactive functional programming (FRP) works well in React and Angular so it seemed like a good fit for Blazor as well.

My review:

- The setup was pretty easy. I took a few notes from [this arcticle](https://www.reactiveui.net/blog/2020/07/article-blazor-compelling-example) and the code behind it.
- I used DynamicData as well, which for me is somehow already part of the whole ReactiveUI stack. It fit very well into the whole application layout, although most of the components in Blazorise do not support the appropriate listeners for collection changes - there you need to support a bit with your code. I absolutely recommend using DynamicData as proxy/cache for your APIs though - state management has never been easier.
- The easy form validation, which was a near natural fit for the Blazorise components was for me one of the major selling points - because I rely heavily on dynamic forms.
- I am not too happy with the routing and IoC approaches yet. I am used to Autofac for most of my development, which I could easily use my services although for my views and viewmodels I had to rely on a service locator pattern (with Splat backed by Autofac).

Answer (score 3):

ReactiveUI is never finished, but there are working samples for Blazor Server-Side (which is now released as of AspNetCore 3.1) and also working samples for Blazor Hosted and Blazor Client models in the ReactiveUI.Samples repository.

[You can find the direct link here](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/master/blazor)